# Who am I, and when will I appear?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> I came regularly once a year, from '05 to '08,
>   Barely staggered through the next couple of years,
>   Returned in 2010, and broke in 2011.
>   In '12 and '13 I was only half there,
>   But in '14 and '15 I was back like clockwork.
>   This year I didn't appear at all!

**Who am I?** And when will I next appear?

Comment: When you say "Barely staggered through the next couple of years", you're referring to '08 and '09?

Comment: @Alenanno The couple of years from '08 to '10, yes.

Comment: Google Mode Activated!

Comment: The apostrophes make me very suspicious.

Comment: Sounds almost like the Blackberry phone

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it's

> Dr. Who TV Series

I came regularly once a year, from '05 to '08,

> It was relaunched in 2005. Lines from Wikipedia **Doctor Who finally**
> **returned with the episode "Rose" on BBC One on 26 March 2005. There**
> **have since been nine further series in 2006–2008.** It was not
> broadcasted in year 2009. By broke it means, it was broken with a mid-season 
> finale

In '12 and '13 I was only half there,

> The series was broken into pieces and was not broadcasted fully in 2012 and 2013.

But in '14 and '15 I was back like clockwork.

> It reappeared with Series 8 and Series 9 in 2014 and 2015. Thanks to @Paolo 
> for this from one of the reference - "Series 8 opens with a swooping
> shot through the gears of a clock before the Tardis spins into view,
> spiralling through a surrealist vortex of clock faces. It became a
> viral hit on YouTube, notching over 885,000 views, and Moffat was one
> of them."

This year I didn't appear at all!

> Has not been broadcasted yet while its being filmed.

Who am I? And when will I next appear?

> You are Dr. Who and will appear next year 2017. April 2017 specifically.

Comment: I think "But in '14 and '15 I was back like clockwork." is a reference to the updated opening titles.

Comment: "I came regularly **once a year**" tends to point at something that generally has one appearance a year, would would rule out a TV series.

Comment: @Rubio - Well, if you consider a TV series as a generic thing, it comes alone once an year with its episodes. So, I would say, I will be waiting for GOT(Game of Thrones) to arrive next year. Makes sense I guess.

Comment: @paolo Thanks for the tip. Makes it better.

Comment: @paolo That was unintentional but brilliant. Originally I just thought of "like clockwork" as in regular, but then I remembered the Series 8/9 opening credits and it fit so well!

Comment: This answer is correct, but you could improve some of it a bit by reading the list of series and episodes starting from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Doctor_Who_serials#Ninth_Doctor). (For instance: there weren't nine series in 2006-2008; and it was broadcast in 2009, though only a few specials.) I can edit to improve some of the explanations if you like.

Comment: Sure. That would be great. I am stuck with a bad keyboard today and still managed to get whatever I could. So, Go ahead! :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> The Perseid Meteor shower?

I came regularly once a year, from '05 to '08,

> The Perseid meteor shower comes regularly in mid-august, peaking around August 12 from 2005 to 2008

Barely staggered through the next couple of years,

> In 2009 a Gibbous moon washed out most of the meteors and they were hard to see

Returned in 2010, and broke in 2011.

> In 2011 there was a Full Moon which washed out the sky again, making the shower very faint

In '12 and '13 I was only half there,
But in '14 and '15 I was back like clockwork.
This year I didn't appear at all!

> My theory kind of breaks down here, The dates don't really line up anymore.

If I'm right though, you will reappear

> Next August

Comment: "My theory kind of breaks down here" - that could be a problem :-)

Comment: @rand-al'thor yeah, I'm fairly certain this is wrong, but it does seem like it could be some kind of astrological event, if not the Perseid shower, so I posted it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I will take a mildly wild guess and say

> Friday 13th?
>  I only confirmed with some of the years mentioned but not all yet.
>  It seems that there was 1 Friday the 13th in 2005,6,7,8,10,11.
>  There was more then 1 in 2014 and 2015, and none this year.

EDIT
Seems like I just got lucky with my first few checks.

> It seems there was one Friday 13th this year.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this answer fits the riddle?

Comment: Well, without any constraints this happens every year, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> A recession?

The next time it will return is

> 2017? (About)

EDIT:Just saw the answer, but I'm technically not wrong.

EDIT:
[Proof of reasoning](http://www.zerohedge.com/sites/default/files/images/user3303/imageroot/2015/05/20150513_recess8.jpg)

> Given that the great recession happened between the years of '05 and '08 and that the next line is "barely staggered through the couple of years" meaning at least '09, which is where the great recession ended. There was a recession in '10, which broke in '11. '12 was a pretty normal year but has been half of what recessions have been. '13 was definitely half. '14 it was back, '15 too, and recessions work like clockwork because they always happen. And technically a recession won't happen this year because the recession was big enough from '15 to keep us recovering this year.

Comment: Wecome to Puzzling SE, Xelot. You need to explain your answer.

Comment: Given that the great recession happened between the years of '05 and '08 and that the next line is "barely staggered through the couple of years" meaning at least '09, which is where the great recession ended. There was a recession in '10, which broke in '11. '12 was a pretty normal year but has been half of what recessions have been. '13 was definitely half. '14 it was back, '15 too, and recessions work like clockwork because they always happen. And technically a recession won't happen this year because the recession was big enough from '15 to keep us recovering this year.

Comment: You might want to edit that into your actual answer instead of putting it as a comment.