# Who am I, and when will I appear? the second

Tags: riddle, knowledge

*(with apologies to [@Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor), whose [latest puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45103/who-am-i-and-when-will-i-appear) inspired me to post this one, my first here—and whose text I <del>blatantly stole</del> lovingly adapted in homage.)*

> I came regularly once a year, from '92 to '95,
>   Skipped 1996 entirely,
>   Returned in 1997, and took a break after 1998.
>   I made a few appearances between '05 and '13,
>   But in '15 I was back like clockwork.
>   This year I haven't appeared at all!

**Who am I?** And when will I next appear?

Comment: is the 'once a year' literal this time around in that it only happens once a year, or is it like rand al'thor's question where it happened more than once in those years?

Comment: this happened literally once in each year where it happened.

Comment: @MMAdams For the record, once means once in my question too: one series per year from 2005 to 2008.

Comment: It looks to be ***almost*** a [leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), but that doesn't fit with ***regularly** once a year, from '92 to '95* because the first 3 of those were on Jun 30, but in 1995 the leap second was added on Dec 31.

Comment: "regularly" was in that place in @randal'thor's original puzzle, so I left it.  if that alone prevents you from making  an answer, don't let it.

Comment: @Rubio: If that's the answer you should change the question text.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but el nino fits -- minus '13 and obviously this year.

Comment: @Pat That seems like an answer rather than a comment -- why not post it as one?

Comment: So does FumbleFingers'. Someone just post an answer already :)

Comment: ... though if either of them is right, "when will I next appear" is a rather tricky question.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan No, the next leap second is planned for 31 December at 12:59:60 pm UTC.

Comment: actually 11:59:60 pm UTC, or 23:59:60 UTC.  I'll point out here that the title of this riddle is no accident.  anyone gonna actually make an answer out of all this yet? hehe

Comment: I just came here to make that remark about the title but Rubio had got there first :-). @FumbleFingers should do it and get all that lovely lovely rep.

Comment: If you post your answer, @FumbleFingers, you can get full credit. Feel free to use/adapt the graphic from the accepted-for-now CW answer, which would then be unnecessary.

Comment: @humn: I'm mostly active on [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions), where standards are probably different (if a question contains something significantly misleading we'd rather see it edited than simply have people make assumptions that might be mistaken). Ty for the offer, but I'll graciously decline and keep my eyes open for a well-formed puzzle here that I can answer. Admittedly, a somewhat forlorn hope, since I'm not actually that quick-witted when it comes to riddles (I just got lucky on this one! :)

Comment: You're given credit here in any case, @FumbleFingers, perhaps appropriately in written English rather than points then.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I left the word *regularly* in as once per year is indeed regular - and because the puzzle I was intentionally mirroring used the word there (and in a similar inexact sense). Spelling out a puzzle with zero ambiguities is possible, sure, but I think leaving something that needs to be puzzled over how it might fit is part of the fun. In any case you were the first (and maybe only) one to hit on the right answer, which I would have loved to give you due credit for - well done, and I hope you stick around Puzzling :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from a
[comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45111/who-am-i-and-when-will-i-appear-the-second#comment135912_45111)
by
[FumbleFingers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19177/fumblefingers),
who should feel free to make a separate answer and get full credit.

[image]

           
     <sup>(source Wikipedia)</sup>

**Who am I?**

> [**A leap second**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)

Last seen: 
[image]
[<sup>(from Wikipedia)</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Leap_Second_-_30_June_2015.png)

And when will I next appear?

> Saturday

> December 31, 2016, at 23:59:**60** UTC